# Any Haskell online contests or problem sets?

Tags: haskell

Do you know any online problem sets or contests that accept solutions in Haskell? I know only [El Judge](http://acm.mipt.ru/twiki/bin/view/ELJudge/WebHome), but unfortunately it has some problems with ghc, so any Haskell problem is rejected with "memory limit" resolution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Sphere Online Judge (SPOJ)](http://www.spoj.pl)

It uses ghc 6.10.4 compiler.

Answer (score 15):

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) problems are quite a good fit for Haskell. You run your own code and submit your answer on the website.

Answer (score 9):

[Facebook Puzzles](http://www.facebook.com/careers/puzzles.php) (GHC Haskell 6.8.2)

Answer (score 6):

[Code Chef](http://www.codechef.com/) accepts Haskell.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [99 haskell problems](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/H-99%3a_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems)

Answer (score 4):

[Google Code Jam](http://code.google.com/codejam/)

Comment: Like project Euler and ICFP, this is “bring your own compiler”; only the solutions are machine-checked.

Answer (score 4):

[Coderforces.com](http://codeforces.com/)

You can also see how others have solved a problem using Haskell, e.g., submissions by [watashi](http://codeforces.com/submissions/watashi) and [jbin](http://codeforces.com/submissions/bjin) (jbin and watashi are both ACM-ICPC world finals champions, in 2012 and 2010 respectively.)

jbin's github: https://github.com/bjin/puzzles

Answer (score 3):

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net)

Answer (score 2):

- [exercism](http://exercism.io/) has exercises in Haskell.
- [CodinGame](http://www.codingame.com/) accepts.
- others like [UVa Online Judge](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/), Google Code Jam, Project Euler and etc, don't require a specific programming language.

Additionally, there's the [Programming Contests](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Programming_contests) page in Haskell.org.

Comment: Actually, UVa Judge only supports some languages (C, C++, Java, Pascal) on their solution submission + checker...

Comment: For codingame, I've started to blog haskell solutions here: http://foobarcode.me/tag/codingame/

Answer (score 1):

Did you just miss [ICFP Programming Contest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICFP_Programming_Contest)?

Answer (score 0):

- [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/environment): HaskellPlatform 2013.2.0.0 + logict lens pipes mwc-random hashtables regex-pcre hmatrix aeson and hashmap libraries
- [HackerEarth](http://www.hackerearth.com/docs/judge/#language-compilers): GHC 7.4.1